# How do I get a nodes authors email address within views?

Tags: views, nodes, users, emails

I have a view that list nodes of a certain type. These nodes are created by different users.

In my view, how would I get the email address of the creator of the particular node (I will pass this email to a webform)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create the view of content type or use existing view
2. Go to admin/structure/views and edit your view
3. Under advanced section tab **add relationship** `Content: Author`
4. Add the relationship.
5. Add the email field `User: E-mail (E-mail)` under field section.
6. Save the view

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for a detailed answer (and even screenshots!). Luckily this was more simple than I thought.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a view of content type
2. Add required fields
3. Add relationship of user named node content author

[image]

4. Again Add field of author name and email.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this answer also. This is the correct answer as well (but it is the same as as the previous answer).

Comment: @puudutus It looks like this answer was posted first (if you hover over the date you get a tooltip with the exact time), was the answer edited after being posted that you decided to accept the other one?

Comment: You are correct. The other answer was higher, so I assumed it had come first (they both came very fast). Is it custom to mark this as the answer even though the other answer is much more detailed (more helpful if someone is not accustomed to views) and both answers came very close to each other (theres an 8 minute difference)?